# mismatched comparison in XC8

Tags: c, embedded, xc8

Mismatched comparsion when a definition EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE is compared with a variable eusart_rx_buffer_rd of type uint8_t. But if the type of the variable is changed to uint16_t the warning is gone. Why?

```
#define EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE 256
uint8_t eusart_rx_buffer_rd = 0;            

if (eusart_rx_buffer_rd >= EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE)                 
 {
     eusart_rx_buffer_rd = 0;
 }
```

Comment: How can `uint8_t` ever be greater then 256?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks man. How stupid I am. How did I missed it!

Comment: @KamilCuk ...  or equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit type of the literal constant 256 is `int`, so you are comparing an `int` with a `uint8_t`.

The comparison itself causes an implicit promotion to `int`, but is in any case *always* false since 256 is not representable by a `uint8_t`.

It is not clear what the appropriate solution might be, but if all values of the `uint8_t` variable are valid, the test serves no purpose, and a naive change to a larger type may in fact introduce bugs by allowing invalid values to be assigned.